# PySpark not picking the custom schema in csv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am struggling with a very basic pyspark example and I don't know what is going on and would really appreciate if some could help me out

Below is my pypsark code to read a csv file which contains three column

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("Sample App").getOrCreate()
child_df1 = spark.read.csv("E:\\data\\person.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True,multiLine=True)
child_df1.printSchema()
```

Below is the output of above code

```
root
 |-- CPRIMARYKEY: long (nullable = true)
 |-- GENDER: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FOREIGNKEY: long (nullable = true)

child_df1.select("CPRIMARYKEY","FOREIGNKEY","GENDER").show()
```

Output

```
+--------------------+----------------------+------+
|       CPRIMARYKEY  |FOREIGNKEY            |GENDER|
+--------------------+----------------------+------+
| 6922132627268452352|  -4967470388989657188|     F|
|-1832965148339791872|    761108337125613824|     F|
| 7948853342318925440|   -914230724356211688|     M|
```

The issue comes when I provide the custom schema

```
import pyspark.sql.types as T

child_schema = T.StructType(
[
    T.StructField("CPRIMARYKEY", T.LongType()),
    T.StructField("FOREIGNKEY", T.LongType())
]
```

)

```
child_df2 = spark.read.csv("E:\\data\\person.csv",schema=child_schema,multiLine=True,header=True)

child_df2.show()

+--------------------+----------------------+
|       CPRIMARYKEY  |FOREIGNKEY|
+--------------------+----------------------+
| 6922132627268452352|                  null|
|-1832965148339791872|                  null|
| 7948853342318925440|                  null|
```

I am not able to understand that when inferring schema spark can recognize long value however when providing schema , its putting null values  for FOREIGNKEY column. I am struggling with this simple exercise for a very long time and no luck. Could someone please point me out on what I am missing. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you said the CSV has 2 columns.
so the FOREGINKEY and GENDER columns are de-facto one.
so Spark tries to parse -4967470388989657188,F as Long and returns null because it's not a valid long.

Can you add the Gender column to the schema and see if it fixes FOREGINKEY?

If you don't want the gender column, instead of removing it in the schema just `.drop('gender')` after reading the csv.

Comment: csv has 3 columns.

Comment: The solution that you provided worked. Thanks . I was under the impression that whatever column I specify in the custom schema, spark will read only those column.